# Which python libraries do you recommend for label ranking?

Tags: python, ranking

I'm currently looking for python libraries that offer models for the label ranking problem. So provided with a context x and a set of Labels Y, the model should output a ranking of those labels.

I'm mostly interested in models that implements the Ranking by comparison method (RPC) and the Plackett-Luce Model.

I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Have you looked into existing libraries like https://choix.lum.li/en/latest/? Anything that doesn't work here for you?

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your comment! It seems that the models in choix expect a list of rankings but without context. What I'm interested in is the following: I have a set of labels {A,B,...} and based on a context x, I would like to get a ranking, so for example f(x) = [B,C,A,...]. As I understand, choix only takes rankings without context (and aggregates them?) , but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Does it have to be Python?  There are existing r packages that can do what you want https://hturner.github.io/PlackettLuce/ .  For python I have found TF Probability implementation which you can use as last layer in a neural network that takes 'x' as input https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/PlackettLuce

Comment: I will give it a try! thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: I also think PlackettLuce only takes rankings, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this github repository  https://github.com/JasonLC506/LabelRanking that implements some algorithms that I found pretty useful. It only supports python2, but I was able to convert it locally using future https://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html.

I have no problems so far, everything seems to be working fine!